# Proc sql subtotals and subqueries

Tags: sas

I am very new to Proc sql and feel like I'm hitting my head against a wall. Basically, I want to make some different types of subtotals, and I've been struggling. I can figure out how to do it in two sql statements, but I can't figure out how to combine them into one statement using a subquery, which seems like it should be possible.

Sample data

```
*job, gender
*florist, female
*florist, female
*florist, male
*florist, male
*Manager, female
*Manager, female
*Manager, female
*Manager, male
*nurse, female
*nurse, female
*nurse, male
```

What I want to wind up getting from my code is:

```
Job Title|  Gender  | All answers to gender | Job by gender
Florist  |  female  | 7                     | 2
Florist  |  male    | 4                     | 2
Manager  |  female  | 7                     | 3
Manager  |  male    | 4                     | 1
nurse    |  female  | 7                     | 2
nurse    |  male    | 4                     | 1
```

My current code (which does it in two steps) is

```
proc sql;
    create table newdata as
          select gender, job,
            count(gender) as GenderCount
          from datasource where gender in ('f','m')
          group by gender;

     select * from newdata;
quit

proc sql;
     create table newdata2 as 
            select *,
             count(gender) as JobsByGender
            from newdata
            group by q1, q21;

      select distinct * from newdata2 order by q21, q1;
      quit;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing "select * from newdata" at the end of your first proc sql statement?

Comment: Also, is there any reason for you not to use more than one proc sql statement? Do you just want the data together in one table?

Comment: yes, I want it in one table, partially because I'm going to have to have it do this a lot of times. I probably have some unnecessary junk there because I'm a super beginner and am using similar sample code to figure out how I'm doing this, and am trying to mess with it as little as possible because I feel like I am not really understanding what each part is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join a subquery to get your expected result:

```
proc sql;
    create table newdata as
        select bd.job,
            bd.gender,
            sq.count_gender,
            count(bd.job) as JobsByGender
        from basedata bd
        inner join
            (select gender,
                 count(gender) as count_gender
             from base_data
             group by gender) sq
        on sq.gender = bd.gender
        group by bd.job, bd.gender;
quit;
```

The subquery creates a dataset that looks like

```
Gender | count_gender
---------------------
Male   | 4
Female | 7
```

The inner join matches up the correct number to each gender, as specified by `on sq.gender = bd.gender`

Honestly, most of this is just generic SQL. If you are going to be doing more proc sql statements in the future, I would highly suggest going over the tutorials that can be found at http://www.sqlcourse.com/ and http://www.sqlcourse2.com/

These will hopefully let you understand the query you are writing rather than using sample code you don't understand.

Comment: it's giving me an error message on the final group by statement:

Comment: ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, HAVING, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, OR, ORDER, ^=, |, ||, ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: In final `GROUP BY` add *sq.count_gender* which is a non-aggregated column in outer query.

Comment: I find that SAS is usually pretty forgiving about missing a column in the group by. Did Parfait's suggestion fix the error message @eee333?

Comment: 'inner join
(select q1,
count(q1) as count_q1
from bd
group by q1) sq
on sq.q1=bd.q1
group by bd.q21 bd.q1 sq.count_q1;' results in an error under the last group by

Comment: for some reason I don't seem to be able to edit or delete my more recent comments, but I realized the issue was that I had accidentally deleted the commas in the group by, which was what caused it to fail.

Comment: Also, thank you to the sql help links--usually if I'm just doing a small bit of code in a language, I'm able to pick it up well enough to do what I need, but like I mentioned above, I'm having difficulty doing that with this. I'd tried some proc sql guides, but they were way too simple to offer any real help, I will definitely check those out

Comment: @eee333 Glad you found the error! I hope those links help you out.